# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys: error

Tags: iphone

i am getting web data from .net web server using NSMutableUrl request.

i am getting the data using soap request after getting i am storing in NSDirectory by parsing response using NSXmlparsing.

my code is

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id", @"firstname", @"lastname",@"addr",@"state",@"country",@"email",@"phone", nil];
    directory = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:resultData forKeys:keys];

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:directory forKey:@"dictionaryKey"];
```

It works fine but when ever if i enter wrong it gets exception like this.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: number of objects (0) not equal to number of keys (8)'
```

i am getting response from web server like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GenericAndroidMethodResponse xmlns="Mortgage"><GenericAndroidMethodResult>&lt;NewDataSet /&gt;</GenericAndroidMethodResult></GenericAndroidMethodResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

And application quits.

But if i got wrong response how can i recognize,at that time i need to display an alert but  not quit from application.

how can i done this.

I think my question is clear.

can any one pls  help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create a dictionary and pass it 8 keys (your `keys` variable), but you are not passing an equal number of values. In fact, Cocoa says your `resultData` is an empty array (or maybe even nil). So you need to protect your code with something like:

```
if ([resultData count] == 8) {
   // Creating the dictionary will succeed.
   directory = ... ;
} else {
   // Creating the dictionary will fail, handle or ignore that.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `resultData` is an `NSArray`, you could test if `[resultData count] == 8`.